# Unit testing class with concrete type member

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following class that I want to test

```
class A
{
public:
  void register()
  {
    b = new B();
  }
...
private:
  B *b;
};
```

How can I mock `b` besides adding a template parameter to `A` ?

Comment: Having a setter for `b`?

Comment: May have a problem naming a member function after the **keyword** `register`.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is your friend - pass a `B` in to your constructor for `A`, so that you can substitute it with a fake version:

```
class A {
public:
   A(B *aB):b(aB) {}

private:
  B *b;
};
```

So that in your test code, you can instantiate an `A` with whatever instance of `B` makes sense.

Comment: Yes, generally dependency injection is a way to go, but I have to create an actual object somewhere eventually, so I can't mock every class?